# wp_list_categories - with custom taxonomy

Tags: wordpress

I'm back struggling with some more coding :(

I have written a custom PHP page to loop through a custom post type. Now what I want is to list the custom posts categories, and have each category link to the same page but pass the category to the query_posts() function.

My code is currently

```
    <div id="left" style="float:left;width:200px">
<b>Categories</b><br><br>
    <?php wp_list_categories( $args );   ?>
</div>  <!-- end of left container -->


<div id="middle" style="float:left;width:700px">

<?php

$args = array(
'post_type'=> 'e-books',
'showposts' => '-1',
'eCats'    => $cat,
'order'    => 'ASC'
);
query_posts( $args );
```

where

```
$cat = $_GET['cat']
```

What I want is each link from the wp_list_categories() to be something like.

```
http://example.com/products.php?cat=fiction
```

Is this possible? I can't get my head around the Walker class :( I've got this far

```
class MyWalker extends Walker_Category {

function start_el(&$output, $category, $depth, $args) {
    extract($args);

    $cat_name = esc_attr( $category->name );
    $cat_name = apply_filters( 'list_cats', $cat_name, $category );
    $link = '<a href="products.php?cat="';
    $link .= $cat_name;
    $link .= '>';
    $link .= $cat_name . '</a>';

    if ( 'list' == $args['style'] ) {
        $output .= "\t<li";
        $class = 'cat-item cat-item-' . $category->term_id;
        if ( !empty($current_category) ) {
            $_current_category = get_term( $current_category, $category->taxonomy );
            if ( $category->term_id == $current_category )
                $class .=  ' current-cat';
            elseif ( $category->term_id == $_current_category->parent )
                $class .=  ' current-cat-parent';
        }
        $output .=  ' class="' . $class . '"';
        $output .= ">$link\n";
    } else {
        $output .= "\t$link<br />\n";
    }
}
}
```

but the links aren't completing - they are showing as

```
?cat=
```

Answer (score -1):

For listing category with the custom taxonomy : 
You can you following code:

`$catnames = get_terms( 'custom taxonomy name');`

Then use foreach loop to disply the category.